# Can the Cloudfront Origin Request Policy be specified in Terraform?

Tags: amazon-cloudfront

Is the [Cloudfront origin request policy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/controlling-origin-requests.html#origin-request-create-origin-request-policy) able to be specified using either Cloudformation or Terraform (ideally Terraform)?

I've seen references for setting it in the console, API or CLI, but no examples using any IaC options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is a Terraform resource for that [cloudfront_origin_request_policy](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/cloudfront_origin_request_policy)

Comment: Not sure how I missed that, but thanks for pointing out the obvious. : )